# charge tax if shipping address or billing is in California

Tags: prestashop-1.6, tax

We want to charge tax if shipping or billing address is in California.

So to summarize, tax should be charged if:

1. Shipping address is California
2. Billing address is California

Do NOT charge tax if shipping and billing address both are outside of California.

Currently in the admin under tax setting I can choose either billing or shipping [drop down].

Please help me to modify the logic

Answer (score 0):

Okay ! So finally I found answer to my own question and below what I did. This can be helpful

I Classes Cart.php under the function `getSummaryDetails()`

after this code

```
`$base_total_tax_inc = $this->getOrderTotal(true);
$base_total_tax_exc = $this->getOrderTotal(false);`
```

I have added `$my_product_total = $this->getProductOrderTotal(true);`

Where the function `getProductOrderTotal()` which I have written in order to get the total product price in the cart. After this, I have added

```
`

    if($invoice->id_state==5 AND $delivery->id_state!=5){
                $total_tax = ($my_product_total*8)/100;
                $base_total_tax_inc=$base_total_tax_inc+$total_tax;
             }
               else{ $total_tax = $base_total_tax_inc - $base_total_tax_exc;}

`
```

5 is the id for California.

Notice `AND $delivery->id_state!=5` in my IF condition. This I do because the delivery address is already set in the system(From Back admin) to TRUE.